# Convert *.doc to *.csv using macros

Tags: vba, excel, csv, libreoffice-calc

I want to convert a doc file to csv via running the macros.

I am able to do that manually but a new to VBA so needed help to write the code.

Manual Steps:

1. Copy the contents of `doc` to `xls` file with `PASTE SPECIAL` mode and unformatted text.
2. Then carry out the `TRIM` function and transpose the rows and columns.
3. Now save the contents to a new `CSV` file.

Comment: record a macro while saving a file as csv and check your VBE modules and there you go.

Comment: There's no reason to do this in to Excel and then to CSV, you can write text directly to a CSV. See deru's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Is the doc file in a correct Format to write as CSV? Then I would do it like

```
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdLine, count:=1
Selection.Text 'Text to write
```

in a Loop of all Lines in your Sheet

Here you can see how to write in a File using VBA:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472596/write-a-line-in-a-txt-file

If you whant to do it as you typed above you can also use the record Macro function in Word or Excel